# Insert and parsing .eml files in SQL Server or R

Tags: c#, sql-server, r, ssis

I currently have some .eml files on my local disk in which I would like to parse/insert into sql server 2014.

I have seen some ways to do this via C# however, I am unfamiliar with that language.

I am comfortable in analyzing the data via SQL or in R and also running a procedure using SSIS.

Also let us assume that I need all the fields in the .eml files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Before this tasks were performed using mimefilt.dll
I recommend checking this file documentation and try to register again SQL
Not quite sure how to make it with 2014 version
Regards

Answer (score 0):

One hack way that I found out to do this is to use software to convert eml files to csvs and upload it via import or SSIS.

The software I used was PSTViewer Pro which can convert the email files to a flat CSV file. Very Handy.

Thank you all!